# PowerShell - Trouble exporting to CSV file

Tags: arrays, csv, powershell

Ok, I'm having an issue with exporting data from a PowerShell script into a CSV file.  Here's the code:

```
$UserArray = @(Import-CSV "C:\UserProfiles.csv")
$DeleteArray = @()

Foreach ($user in $userArray)
    {
    $useremail = $user.email
    $Domain1Account = Get-ADUser -filter {mail -eq $useremail} -server dc1.domain.local
    If ($Domain1Account -eq $Null)
        {
        $Domain2Account = Get-ADUser -filter {mail -eq $useremail} -server dc2.domain2.local
        If ($Domain2Account -eq $null)
        {
        "User " + $user.email + " does not exist."
        $DeleteArray = $DeleteArray + $user.email
        }
    }
Else {"User found!!! " + $user.email + " exists in AD!!!"}
}
```

Essentially, I'm trying to take an existing CSV file and see if the user exists in one of two different domains by searching for their email address.  If they don't exist in either domain, I'd like to export that list of email addresses (the $DeleteArray list) back out as a different .CSV file.

The problem is, every time I use something like this:

```
$DeleteArray | Export-CSV "C:\DeletedUsers.csv"
```

all I get back is a CSV file with:

```
Length
32
31
29...
```

instead of what I want:

```
email1@domain.com
email2@domain5.com
email5@domain4.com...
```

What am I dong wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Export-Csv`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx) is a little too smart for itself in this instance.

It tries to discover what properties the input objects have, in order to construct meaningful column names.

Since the input objects are all of type `String` and a string only has 1 property (the `Length` of the string), `Export-Csv` ends up exporting that as the only column in your CSV.

You can use `Select-Object` to control subsequent "column creation":

```
$DeleteArray |Select-Object @{Name="Email";Expression={$_}} |Export-CSV "C:\DeletedUsers.csv"
```

Alternatively, since you're *not really* interested in a CSV, but just a list of strings, use `Out-File` instead:

```
$DeleteArray | Out-File C:\DeletedUsers.txt
```

Comment: Thank you!  The first snippet of code ('Select-Object...') is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

You need to pipe *objects* with the desired properties to the `Export-Csv` cmdlet, not string objects like those that exist in your array. One example is to use the `Select-Object` cmdlet with a calculated property.

```
$DeleteArray | Select-Object @{n='Email';e={$_}} | Export-CSV "C:\DeletedUsers.csv"
```