# Powershell export-csv return numbers

Tags: csv, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm having trouble understanding why my csv export only return numbers instead of the string I want. Everything looks good when I use out-file but not export-csv.

```
$get_child_csv = Get-ChildItem $c_path -ErrorVariable +errors | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | select fullname | foreach {$_.fullname} | Export-Csv ".\childitems\csv\$item.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding unicode
$get_child_txt = Get-ChildItem $c_path -ErrorVariable +errors_txt | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | select fullname | foreach { $_.fullname } | Out-File ".\childitems\txt\$item.txt"
```

CSV output example:

```
Length
41
41
41
41
```

TXT output:

```
\\SERVER\FILESHARE\FOLDER
\\SERVER\FILESHARE\FOLDER
\\SERVER\FILESHARE\FOLDER
\\SERVER\FILESHARE\FOLDER
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Remove `foreach { $_.fullname }`.

Comment: If I do, the output wont be the same as the txt file. The table title will be shown at the top.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell - Trouble exporting to CSV file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796291/powershell-trouble-exporting-to-csv-file)

Comment: @user1945911 that's what CSV is. First row is a header of property-names. If you only want the paths then don't use export-csv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Export-CSV` is used to export objects with multiple properties. The format of the output is one object per row with the first row being a header describing the columns/properties of the rows below ex.:

```
Property1,Property2
11,12
21,22
```

You are trying to export the string-value for the `FullName`-property because of the following code `foreach { $_.FullName } | Export-CSV ...`. A string object only has one property which is "Length" as you can see below, which is the reason why your CSV only contains the Length header and the length of each path (one per row):

```
PS > Get-ChildItem | foreach {$_.fullname} | Get-Member -MemberType Properties   

   TypeName: System.String

Name   MemberType Definition       
----   ---------- ----------       
Length Property   int Length {get;}
```

If you only want to save the paths (single property/value), then you should NOT use `Export-CSV`, but rather `Out-File`, `Set-Content` to create a normal textfile:

```
Get-ChildItem $c_path | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | foreach { $_.fullname } | Out-File ".\childitems\txt\$item.txt"
```

If you want to use valid CSV (which needs a header), then you could remove `foreach {$_.fullname} |` to get this output:

```
PS > Get-ChildItem $c_path -ErrorVariable +errors | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | select fullname | Export-Csv ".\childitems\csv\$item.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding unicode

FullName
Path1
Path2
```

Sidenote: You could convert the object to CSV, skip the first line (header) and then save using `Out-File` etc. like the sample below to get a header-less csv-file, but there's really no reason to use CSV for a single property/column/value per object.

```
PS > gci | select fullname | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1
"C:\Users\frode\3D Objects"
"C:\Users\frode\Contacts"
"C:\Users\frode\Desktop"
```

Answer (score 2):

**ANSWER**

Frode F. is right in explaining why it wasn't working as expected, but there IS a simple way to grab an array of strings and throw them into a CSV from the pipe:

```
'first','second','third' |
     ForEach-Object {New-Object psobject -Property @{'String' = $_}} |
     Export-Csv ".\string_example.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want this part for reuse as a one-liner in the pipe:

```
%{New-Object psobject -Prop @{$propName=$_}}
```

*(just need to define $propName ahead of time or replace $propName with a string)*

**EXPLANATION**

By using `ForEach{New-Object}`, we are taking each string in the array, and explicitly creating an object with a named property who's value is the string in the pipeline.

Revisiting what Frode F. said, `Export-Csv` is going to grab Properties from the objects it is passed.  If you want to compare the Property members of the original way vs with `ForEach{New-Object}`, try the following code:

```
$stringArray = 'first','second','third'

# Original
$stringArray |
     Get-Member -MemberType Properties

# With ForEach{New-Object}
$stringArray |
     ForEach-Object {New-Object psobject -prop @{'String' = $_}} |
     Get-Member -MemberType Properties
```

This results in the following:

```
   TypeName: System.String

Name   MemberType Definition       
----   ---------- ----------       
Length Property   int Length {get;}


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name     MemberType   Definition                        
----     ----------   ----------                        
String   NoteProperty System.String String=first
```

The entries in the "Name" field will be used as headers by Export-Csv, while the "Definition" section will be used as the contents.  Note that the "Definition" field lists the type of data that will be passed on--int in the original and string with the `ForEach{New-Object}` method.

Comment: I run into this issue a lot because I tend to use `Select -Expand $propName` to strip strings out of bigger objects.